# Aquamacs does not work with with Agda Mode

Tags: cabal, agda, aquamacs

I have recently installed Agda to my machine as well as Aquamacs. The problem is that Aquamacs does not have Agda mode readily available.
When I run `agda-mode` locate I get the following:

```
lukemccartney@Lukes-MacBook-Pro ~ % agda-mode locate
/usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.6.4.1/libexec/ghc-9.8.1/Agd-2.6.4.1-a0516ce5/share/emacs-mode/agda2.el
```

When running `agda-mode setup` I get the following:

```
lukemccartney@Lukes-MacBook-Pro ~ % agda-mode setup
Loading /usr/local/Cellar/agda/2.6.4.1/libexec/ghc-9.8.1/Agd-2.6.4.1-a0516ce5/share/emacs-mode/agda2.el (source)...
The .emacs file used: /Users/lukemccartney/.emacs
It seems as if setup has already been performed.
```

When I run `agda-mode compile` I get the following:

```
lukemccartney@Lukes-MacBook-Pro ~ % agda-mode compile
Loading quail/latin-ltx...
```

I don't know how to get Agda to work with Aquamacs.